Session invalidation on server restart of Webpshere Liberty
I am using the websphere liberty application server with below configuration in server.xml
 <httpSession cookieName="MyAppJSESSIONID" cookiePath="/myapp" invalidateOnUnauthorizedSessionRequestException="true"/>
 <webAppSecurity includePathInWASReqURL="true" ssoCookieName="myappLTPATOKEN"/>

The session is getting invalidated properly when using the logout from application and asking for login again but I want the same behavior on server restart. Currently if I restart the liberty server, the old JESSIONID persist in the browser and not asking for login. Does liberty have any specific configuration to invalidate all the session on server restart. Thanks.

Session will not be invalidated on server restart as this is part of the session failover scenario. That is, when session persisted on the backend, server failure (restarted) should always able to resume session from the backend.
However if server restarted, security token is no longer valid on the server side, it will give UnauthorizedSessionRequestException on the request. invalidateOnUnauthorizedSessionRequestException="true" will invalidate the session.

Just found out from the security team, the security token will be valid until it reaches expiration time and it will be in the browser. Therefore it will be valid even server restarted.  There is no option to force a token to expire unless you did a logout.
